# How do I get back to the beginning in kcachegrind?

Tags: kcachegrind

Sometimes I run kcachegrind, click around awhile, hit the little 'x' that closes the left panel (oops! no idea how to get it back), click around some more, get totally lost, then exit kcachegrind.

Then I later re-run kcachegrind again on the same input file, hoping to start afresh, but instead, kcachegrind "helpfully" remembers the broken state I was in and puts me back there, i.e. totally lost and with a missing panel that I have no idea how to get back.

How do I recover?

- Hitting Up,Up,Up... doesn't help me find node "main" because I'm in a cycle, and main isn't even in the current call graph because I'm in a thread.
- File->Reload doesn't help.
- View->Layout-> Restore To Default doesn't help.
- Renaming the input file doesn't help.
- Removing and re-installing kcachegrind doesn't help.

How do I get back to the beginning?  That is, default layout, default node, default everything else.

I'm using KCachegrind Version 0.7.4kde on ubuntu 14.04.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I found this by using the strace program.

```
rm ~/.kde/share/config/kcachegrindrc
```

Comment: For OS X, see my answer at http://stackoverflow.com/a/42938536/539149 for right clicking the top bar to show the view menu.

Comment: Arch Linux: ~/.config/kcachegrindrc