# qcachegrind "flat profile" dock panel disappeared. how to restore?

Tags: macos, homebrew, kcachegrind

I installed qcachegrind on OS X via brew. No problems. I generated a few *.callgrind files and viewed them with qcachegrind. Again, no problem. While viewing one file I accidentally closed the "flat profile" dock panel. Now anytime I open qcachegrind that panel is missing.

I tried running `lsof` to figure out where qcachegrind was getting its preferences, but that didn't help. I deleted a file from `~/Library/Preferences/io.github.qcachegrind.plist` that appeared to store window position data, but that still hasn't resolved the issue. This screenshot illustrates the problem; also note that there are no menus available to pull down either.

[image: screen shot]

Someone else posted a similar query for kcachegrind that was answered here: [How do I get back to the beginning in kcachegrind?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35647615/how-do-i-get-back-to-the-beginning-in-kcachegrind)

However, that solution doesn't work for OSX.

Anyone have a clue what file needs modification or deletion to restore default window behavior and position for qcachegrind?

Answer (score 2):

**Right click** anywhere on the top bar and select `Flat Profile` from the popup menu:

[image]

Update: clicking on the top bar of the sub-panes also works (in case you hide the Main Toolbar).

The `Settings` menu doesn't seem to be reachable on Mac OS X, and I couldn't find any mention of `~/.kde/share/config/kcachegrindrc` on my hard drive for `rm`.

More info at section 3.4.1 on page 14 of https://docs.kde.org/stable4/en/kdesdk/kcachegrind/kcachegrind.pdf

Comment: On ubuntu, this would be the file to delete would be ~/.config/kcachegrindrc